# Re-index Primary Key of related tables of MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, primary-key, reindex

I have tables related like this

Table: users

| ID_EMP | ID_AREA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 9 |

Table: area

| ID_AREA | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | a |
| 5 | b |
| 7 | c |
| 9 | d |

And I would like them to be like this

| ID_EMP | ID_AREA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 |

| ID_AREA | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | d |

Except this goes on for hundreds of records and lots of tables. I want to organize the primary keys and the foreign keys related to the modified pk.

Also, I used identity(1 , 1) to create the primary keys.

Any suggestion?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1) mysql does not have identity(1,1) type, it has auto_increment. Did you mix mysql up with ms sql server? 2) why do you want to assign new values to pks?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it.

The core feature of the primary key is that it needs to be unique. It doesn't need to be sexy, good looking, or follow a specific pattern or structure. If this is the case, then you probably want to expose it in the UI or to another app as a web service or other.

Good looking keys usually go hand in hand with "natural keys". Avoid natural keys, since they are keys... until the aren't. If a key is exposed on the UI (or to other app/client) *its value will matter* to someone, and that someone will want to change it at some point. Even SSNs can be recycled.

If you need to expose a "key", then create a secondary generated unique column that can serve as the "exported key" for other clients.

Internally, your key is simple and foremost, **unique** (and ugly, who cares).